# python stemming words for local languages

Tags: python

I've some problem to stem words in my local language using rule based algorithm. so any body who are python literate can help me.

In my language some words are pluralized by repeating the first 2 or 3 characters(sounds).

For example

```
Diimaa (root word)  ==> Diddiimaa(plural word)
Adii (root word)   ==> Adadii(plural word)
```

so now i want my program to reject "Did" from the first example and "Ad" from the second example

the following is my code and it did not return any result

```
`def compput(mm):   
    vv=1
    for i in mm:
        if seevowel(i)==1:
            inxt=mm.index(i)+1
            if inxt<len(mm)-1 and seevowel(mm[inxt])==0: 
                vv=vv+1            
    return vv
def stemm_maker(tkn):
    for i in range(len(tkn)):
        if (i[0] == i[2] and i[1] == i[3]):
            stem = i[2:]
            if compput(stem) > 0:
                return stem
        elif ((i[0] == i[2] or i[0]== i[3]) and i[1] == i[4]):
            stem = i[3:]
            if compput(self) > 0:
                return stem
       else:
           return tkn
    print(stem)`
```

Comment: Consider giving some useful name to your variable please... It would be easier to understand

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Do you already have Aadii -> Adadii and want to process it further? Please state clearly what is input and expected output (and what is actual output)

Comment: I want adii as root word after processing Adadii i.e eliminating the first two characters "Ad" no worry about case

Comment: Your examples show more complex cases than you describe. Diimaa->Diddiimaa not just repeats the first two characters, but introduce an additional 'd'. Aadii->Adadii inserts a 'd' between the first two 'a'-s. So, what are exactly the rules? And are there singular words, that start with letter repeating? (Parsing natural languages is pretty hard.)

Comment: yes! but by if else method I tried to put that exceptional. my problem is how I put character at 0 index  if it is equal to character at 2 index i.e value of i[0] == value of i[2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer for my question posted on this page. I tried the following rule based code and it works correctly. I've checked my code with words assigned to jechoota

```
jechoota = "diddiimaa adadii babaxxee babbareedaa gaggaarii guguddaa hahhamaa hahapphii"

token = jechoota.split()
def stem(word):
    if(word[0] == word[2] and word[1] == word[3]):
        stemed = word[2:]
    elif(word[0] == word[2] and word[0] == word[3] and word[1] == word[4]):
        stemed = word[3:]
    return stemed
for i in token:
    print stem(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to attack this problem is with regular expressions.

Looking at these pairs (found [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=gTcMvCKcvhsC&lpg=PA230&ots=fHZQACe7xS&dq=%22Diddiimaa%22&pg=PA230#v=onepage&q=%22Diddiimaa%22&f=false)):

```
adadii       adii
babaxxee     baxxee
babbareedaa  bareedaa
diddiimaa    diimaa
gaggaarii    gaarii
guguddaa     guddaa
hahhamaa     hamaa
hahapphii    happhii
```

the rule appears to be

```
if the word starts with XY...
then the reduplicated word is either XYXY... or XYXXY...
```

In the regex language this can be expressed as

```
^(.)(.)\1?(?=\1\2)
```

which means:

```
 char 1
 char 2
 maybe char 1
 followed by
    char 1
    char 2
```

Complete example:

```
test = {
    'adadii': 'adii',
    'babaxxee': 'baxxee',
    'babbareedaa': 'bareedaa',
    'diddiimaa': 'diimaa',
    'gaggaarii': 'gaarii',
    'guguddaa': 'guddaa',
    'hahhamaa': 'hamaa',
    'hahapphii': 'happhii',
}

import re

def singularize(word):
    m = re.match(r'^(.)(.)\1?(?=\1\2)', word)
    if m:
        return word[len(m.group(0)):]
    return word

for p, s in test.items():
    assert singularize(p) == s
```

Comment: if I've looking in test, that is dictionary based rather rule based. some what it is difficult to put all words in test since there are many such words. any how it is very interesting. thanxs